# How do I create a loop that will generate random numbers until it matches my user input?

Tags: java, loops, random, numbers

I'm very new at java. I'm doing an exercise and I am stuck. Basically I have to

1. Ask the user to pick a random # from  1-100. Ask again if not between those #.
2. Generate random # between 1-100 until it matches the user input.
3. Print matching number and number of tries to get matching number.

So far, I've done this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RoughNums {
   public static void main(String[]args) {
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rand = new Random();
      int rantInt = rand.nextInt(101);

      while(true) {
         System.out.println("Hello friend! Pick a number between 1 - 100: ");
         int pick = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

         if(pick > 100) {
            System.out.println("Oops, number too big! Please try again!\n");
         } else {
            System.out.println("Let's see if I can get the same number too!");
         }

      }

   }
}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. Should I add another while loop? If so, how should I write it? How do I generate random numbers until it matches the user input number?

Comment: Note that `rand.nextInt(101)` generates a number between 0 and 100, not 1 and 100.

Comment: Oh I see. So how should it be written then?

Comment: @TracyNguyen `int rantInt = rand.nextInt(100)+1;`

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple while loop with boolean value for finding it and counter for tries. Also `rand.nextInt(101)` will get number between 0 - 100 so you have to change like I did in example. I initiated `int pick` at the start so we do not create it twice if user input wrong number

```
public class RoughNums{
   public static void main(String[]args){
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rand = new Random();
      int pick;
      int rantInt = 0;
      int tries = 0;
      boolean found = false;

         while(true) {

           System.out.println("Hello friend! Pick a number between 1 - 100: ");
           pick = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

          if(pick > 100){
          System.out.println("Oops, number too big! Please try again!\n");

                  }
          else {
          System.out.println("Let's see if I can get the same number too!");


          break;}

          }      

         while(!found){
             rantInt = rand.nextInt(100) + 1; // Genrating number between 1 - 100
             tries++;
             if(pick == rantInt){
                 found = true;
             }
         }

         System.out.println("Your number is " + rantInt + " and I found it in " + tries + " tries");



      }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to use a `while` loop to get things done and just add a `count` variable to display on how many tries you needed to get the RNG to guess your number. 
Here is the solution based on the code you posted.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RoughNums{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rantInt = rand.nextInt(101);
        int pick;

        while(true) {

            System.out.println("Hello friend! Pick a number between 1 - 100: ");
            pick = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

            if(pick > 100){
                System.out.println("Oops, number too big! Please try again!\n");

            } else if(pick < 1){
                System.out.println("Oops, number too small! Please try again!\n");

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Let's see if I can get the same number too!");


                break;}

        }

        int count = 0;
        while (rantInt != pick){
            count++;
            rantInt = rand.nextInt(101);
        }

        System.out.println( pick + " was found using " + count + " tries.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After getting the user's pick, you will need another while loop to generate random number till it matches user's pick. Basically it may look something like this:

```
int rantInt;
while(true) {
   // Add code to count number of tries
   rantInt = rand.nextInt(101);
   if(rantInt == pick) { break; }  
}
```

Another way to generate random number between min and max (both inclusive) numbers is:

```
int range = max - min + 1; 
int rand = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
```